# Writing a map into a file C++

Tags: c++, file, io

I have two methods of doing this. First one:

```
string output;
for (auto& kv : stored) {
  output.append(kv.second + "\n");
}
insert(file, output);
```

where `insert()` is:

```
void insert(string file, string str) {
  ifstream stream(file);
  stream << str;
  stream.close();
}
```

Second method:

```
ifstream stream(file);
for(auto& kv : stored) {
  stream << kv.second;
}
stream.close();
```

where in both cases, `stored` is of type `map<int, string>`

Which method is more efficient?

**EDIT:**
For the people who are telling me this is a duplicate, I want to know what's the most efficient method to use out of the two, not how to do it.

Comment: Why not benchmark it

Comment: It is hard to judge which one would be faster, better benchmark it. Benchmarking is running your program multiple times (thousands or even millions) and note the time with first method and second method. Although I would prefer method 2, because it appears clearer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider when comparing efficiency of these methods - memory efficiency and time efficiency.

In terms of memory efficiency, the second method is a clear winner, because it requires a fixed amount of additional memory, while the first method requires an amount proportional to the size of the map being written.

In terms of time there should be no noticeable difference, because the operation is dominated by the time it takes to write the file. File access will be slower than anything that you do in memory, including the preparation of the string in the first method.

**Note:** Of course you should make the second method do exactly what the first one does:

```
ofstream stream(file); //To Write into a File, Use "ofstream"
for(auto& kv : stored) {
  stream << kv.second << '\n';
  // Add '\n' character  ^^^^
}
stream.close();
```